# An ImageView behind the ActionBar And The StatusBar in transparent mode

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar, imageview, transparency

I want to make An Image View Like this With the Action Bar And The Status Bar in transparent mode?

[the Image of the ImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HSdy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AppBarLayout to achieve that. [Read this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) if you need help getting started with AppBarLayout and Collapsing Toolbar. You can put an ImageView and a Collapsing Toolbar after that to get that effect and also make sure you have the parallax mode ON for both Toolbar and Imageview.

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

and

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

are important here. Keep the toolbar background transparent and add a back arrow as the navigation icon to the toolbar.

For the status bar part, keep the layout to fit the window using,

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

and use:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

Comment: As soon as I start scrolling up, the image really goes under the Status bar and it has a transparent scrim on it. However, when the Toolbar is expanded, the image is below the StatusBar which has a scrim with the primaryColor.